# R - return data to one row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
ID Name Role_1 Role_2 Role_3
1  Bob  blah   NA     NA
1  Bob  NA     blah   NA
1  Bob  NA     NA     blah
2  Jim  yep    NA     NA
2  Jim  NA     yep    NA
```

How can I end up with the following, returning 1 ID per row?

```
ID Name Role_1 Role_2 Role_3
1  Bob  blah   blah   blah
2  Jim  yep    yep    NA
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the first non-NA value for each `ID` and `Name`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Name) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Role'), ~na.omit(.)[1]))

#    ID Name  Role_1 Role_2 Role_3
#  <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1     1 Bob   blah   blah   blah  
#2     2 Jim   yep    yep    NA
```

In base R :

```
aggregate(.~ID + Name, df, function(x) na.omit(x)[1], na.action = 'na.pass')
```